# Simple filter form layout

Tags: website-design, forms, layout, input-fields

I am making a public movie review website and am having trouble presenting a filter/search form.

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/40sq12oL/) is what it looks like right now. How can I better present it?

Comment: Site reviews, like the one you are requesting, are just too broad and unfocussed for here.

Comment: @AndrewMartin I am *not* asking for a site review. I am asking for design considerations for a specific aspect (a filter/search form) *of* a review site.

Comment: Even so, you are asking us to look the entire page with no single specified problem to solve - this is effectively a review. If you are noticing a specific problem that users are encountering when using your form, then we *may* be able to help. Otherwise, the only recommendation we can truthfully make is to test with users until you can identify that problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your solution user cannot make a combination of filters because you are using a single drop down. Why you are using drop down because probably you didn't ask users what exactly they are looking for. For e.g. use case : user want to search and sort a movie which **has 5 stars** and **has latest reviews** and **newest movie release** cannot be possible with your solution.

What I suggest is break down similar filters:

- By star rating
- Toggle for latest or oldest reviews
- Albhabetically
- Time ?
- Genre
- There could be many.

Just grab 5 people and ask them what they would do when they read review site(you will get what filter they need). Or Test your prototype with them and implement their feedback.

I'd highly suggest [faceted search pattern](https://articles.uie.com/faceted_search/) to solve the use case.

Answer (score 0):

In your case presentation is only the problem means, you can use inline form style as given in the reference.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSW9MX.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>